# How do I change the MVC Bootstrap layout to have more than one columns

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: form example]

I have used the Scaffolded in MVC5 and it created the standard default single column layout for the form.  Some forms are just too long to be single column, so I wanted to modify it into multiple columns as shown in the picture.  I have been messing around with, form-group, row, col-md-*, form-inline...but the formatting is misaligned one way or another.

The solution has to be pretty simple with the right combination of css tags and works with the MVC framework.

The scaffolded standard layout and css

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone please provide a an example of the name, email and website for the comment form as shown that works with the data bind from the view.?

Thanks

@zgood - your answer works with a slight issue, not sure if you know how to fix it.

- I moved the label inside the div with the other text boxes and deleted the horizontal and inline as mentioned
- when you expand it a certain way, the labels with more than one words are mis-aligned.  It's ok if it's just one word though.  Is there a quick fix for that? thanks for the answer.

[image: form example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Wrap all the fields you want in a `<div class="row">` then create the `col-`'s you want (`<div class="col-sm-4">` in this case) and place your `form-groups` inside those columns. Also, I would probably remove any `form-horizontal` or `form-inline` bootstrap classes from your `<form>`

Comment: updated question in response to your solution, slight miss-aligned issue if label is more than one words...

Comment: I guess I didn't need to move the label into the the same text box div as I mentioned in the edited version.  I am just going to take the mis-aligned as inherent having to expand or resize the screen.  Your solution works as is.  thanks.

Comment: @wirble when I make these forms I usually get rid of the `@Html.LabelFor` altogether. I'll add `placeholder = "Label"` to the htmlAttributes object of the `EditorFor` instead, easier than trying to align labels and frees up screen real estate. But that usually depends on the design

Comment: thanks, using what you suggested and a html.label for heading or fieldset works out pretty good.