# Bootstrap two column layout for MVC create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have scaffolded a standard create view for one of my forms using MVC bootstrap. This form however has too many input fields to have in a single column layout, its just too long and seems daft to waste the white space to the right.

I've had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976817/how-do-i-change-the-mvc-bootstrap-layout-to-have-more-than-one-columns) and tried to get it working with my form with not much luck.

In a nutshell I want the address fields to be on the right, in line with all the other fields.

**Razor Snippet**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Department, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

So `AddressLineOne` should be on the same row as `SiteNumber`, `AddressLineTwo` should be on the same rowas `SiteName` and so on and so forth.

This is what I get with the above attempt for the first row:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

How do I achieve this, whilst keeping the labels and standard spacing to the left.

Comment: Create a column <div class="col-md-5"> ... </div> and put all your controls that you want on the left side in it. Then create a second column <div class="col-md-5"> ... </div> and add your controls in it. Add <div class="clearfix"></div> after each row.

Comment: Can you put this in an answer using my examples, only a few rows

Comment: See my answer, I have also put in the css code for the clearfix class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you want.

```
   .clearfix{
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;}


<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Department, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Adjust this to be sm/md/lg, whatever fits best for you -->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Continue your first column of form groups here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Adjust this to be sm/md/lg, whatever fits best for you-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLineOne, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLineTwo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLineTwo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLineTwo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Continue your second column of form groups here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me this with my examples, even just the first two rows

Comment: Edited to reflect your example - first two rows for each column.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to do it like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LOA_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LOA_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LOA_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LI_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LI_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LI_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```